# What is the grade of the hadith "be merciful with the orphan... this will soften your heart"?

Tags: hadith, authenticity

From *Reward of taking care of widows and orphans* ([Islam.ru](http://islam.ru/en/content/story/reward-taking-care-widows-and-orphans), 2014):

> A man once came to the Messenger of Allah, sallallaahu`alaihiwasallam, and complained that he feels hardness in his heart. The Messenger of Allah said, what translated means, "Would you like that your heart becomes soft and that you acquire what you need? Be merciful with the orphan, pat his head and feed him from what you eat. This will soften your heart, and enable you to get what you need." [At-Tabaraanee & As-Silsilah as-Saheehah]

What is the grade of this hadith?

Comment: The hadith is as you displayed compiled in the silsilah as-sahiha of al-Albani so it is a hassan or sahih hadith. If you want more information about the authenticity edit your post as is this looks like a meanless or retorical question.

Answer (score 1):

The Arabic text of the saying of the Messenger of Allah ﷺ is:

> أتحب أن يلين قلبك وتدرك حاجتك؟ ارحم اليتيم وامسح رأسه وأطعمه من طعامك يلن قلبك وتدرك حاجتك

This has been classed as Sahih (صحيح) by al-Albani in [*Sahih al-Jaami as-Sagheer* (80)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/10757/16#p1):

[image]

A hadith having similar meaning but slight variation of wording and transmitted through a different chain, was recorded in Musnad Ahmad, and the chain was classed as Hassan by Ibn Hajar in [Fath al-Bari (كتاب الدعوات)](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1673/6396):

> ولأحمد من حديث أبي هريرة أن رجلا شكى إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم قسوة قلبه فقال أطعم المسكين وامسح رأس اليتيم وسنده **حسن**